# Check words containing in table & the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a `table` which contains some words. I need to check if that word is not in the the table then perform an operation. My dynamically generated `table` looks like this:

```
<div class="newstbl">
  <table>
    <thead>  
      <th>News Name</th>
      <th>News Locale</th>
      </tr>           
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
      <td>Local News Previlege</td>
      <td id="rel">En-US</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I select my dropdown I need to check that selected dropdown word consist or not in the table (not whole word at least some words)

Lets say, if I select my word from dropdown list is `'Global News Previlege'`
then my table consist name `'Local News Previlege'`. In here if both consist `'Previlege'` word then it need to show the alert `'Selected type news already added'`

```
if ($(".newstbl tr:contains('" + NewsArray[0].newstypeName.trim() + "')").length == 0)) {
  alert("Selected type news already added.");
}
```

Comment: It seems like your code is on the right track. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes.Here thisone works for Specific name only.